# Importing generated XML in MS Project 2013

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, ms-project

I am trying to create XML for MS Project 2013 and I have a problem with Tasks.
I create all the necessary tags for Start and Finish data in XML but when imported in MS Project all the Tasks have Finish date same as the Start date. I set Manual schedule to true, but the still did not work. Please advise.

P.S. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytwh4qr3kh7cxzh/Test.xml) you can download my generated XML .

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your XML file suggests that you need to add a Duration tag for each task. If you want to indicate a complete or partially complete task you will also need to add Work and ActualWork tags too, set to appropriate values.

You might find it helpful to generate sample XML files from MS Project to see how it represents particular scenarios, then adjust your generated XML to match.

Comment: The problem is that the exported XML from MS Project is still behaving the same - when it is imported it resets all the Finish dates to the Start ones. I think this is a bug and right now I am contacting the MS support regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

add Duration tags to tasks...change ScheduleFromStart tag value to 0 then its done :)